# Codimension 1 subset of a normal variety is locally principal

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I am trying to prove this result:

Let $X$ be a normal variety, and suppose $W$ is an irreducible closed subvariety of $X$ of codimension $1$. Then there exists an affine open $U$ $\subseteq$ $X$ such that the ideal of  $W \cap U$ in $k[U]$ is principal.

Here is what I got:

Consider the local ring of the subvariety $W$ in $X$. It is a DVR, and suppose its maximal ideal is $M$. Let $\langle U,f\rangle$ be an uniformizing parameter of it. We can very well choose $U$ to be an affine open set. Now consider the ideal of $W \cap U$ in $k[U]$, say it is generated by $g_1,g_2,...,g_n$.

Then from the very definition, we have $\langle U,g_i\rangle$ will be an element of $M$, so there exists $\langle U',f'\rangle$ in $M$ such that $\langle U,f\rangle\langle U',f'\rangle = \langle U,g\rangle$.

But this just means that $g$ is a multiple of $f$ on $U \cap U'$.

How to get that $f|g$ on whole of $U$?

Any help will be appreciated.

Please see: I have knowledge of only the first 5 sections of chapter 1 of Hartshorne, so an elementary proof will be appreciated.

Comment: A note for the future: please use \langle and \rangle instead of < and > when appropriate, as it improves the look of your writing. I've made this change for you this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track. The correct thing to do here is to shrink $U$: since all the $g_i$ are multiples of $f$ in the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,W}$, there exist functions $h_i\in\mathcal{O}_{X,W}$ so that $g_i=fh_i$. Considering these as elements of the function field of $X$, which is exactly the fraction field of $k[U]$, we can write all the $h_i$ as fractions where the denominator doesn't vanish along $W$ by the DVR property. Now take the non-vanishing set in $U$ of the product of all of these denominators: this is affine, and each $g_i$ retricted to this set is an honest multiple of $f$, giving a principal ideal.

Comment: I am not really sure how shrinking $U$ helps... if you shrink $U$ to say $U_1$, then you now need to consider the ideal of $U_1 \cap W$ in $k[U_1]$, and that need not have the same generators $g_1,...,g_n$. Can you please clarify a bit more?

Comment: @Anupam Any set of generators of $I(W\cap U)\subset k[U]$ is a set of generators for $I(W\cap U_1)\subset k[U_1]=k[U]_f$ by sending $g_i$ to $g_i/1$. Why? Suppose there was some element in $I(W\cap U_1)$ not in the ideal generated by them, say $h/f^n$ for $h\in k[U]$. Then after clearing denominators, $h$ isn't in the span of the $g_i$, contradiction.

Comment: Why is $k[U_1]$ the localization of $k[U]$ at $f$?

Comment: @Anupam Because I defined it that way? The nonvanishing locus of a function on an affine is again affine with coordinate algebra given by taking the localization at $f$.

Comment: Where in Hartshorne can I find this result? The closest I have seen is Lemma 4.2, but that only talks about hypersurfaces

Comment: @Anupam The same proof works. Replace $\Bbb A^n$ with an affine variety $X$, and replace $\Bbb A^{n+1}$ by $X\times\Bbb A^1$. Then $D(f)\subset X$ is isomorphic to $V(ft-1)\subset X\times \Bbb A^1$ exactly as in the lemma.